# Ruby on Rails complex search through foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, activerecord

Hi in my application I'm trying to search for an employee based on the skills. I have 3 classes involved Employee, Employee_skills and Skills

Could anyone point me in the direction of how to go about this search as everything I've tried returned errors. Here are their modals.

Employee

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
has_secure_password

has_many :employee_events
has_many :employee_skills , :class_name => EmployeeSkill, :foreign_key => "employee_id"
has_many :employee_projects
has_many :equipments
has_many :time_entry

has_one :holiday 
has_one :role
has_one :skill
has_one :tax

accepts_nested_attributes_for :skill


  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

  def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('empLastName LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    where(:all)
  end
end


  end
```

Employee_skills

```
class EmployeeSkill < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :employee, :class_name => Employee, :foreign_key => "employee_id"
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :skill, :class_name => Skill, :foreign_key => "skill_id"

end
```

Skills

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :employee_skills

def self.search(search)
  where("skillType LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end

end
```

Comment: Why there is a need to have a Skill class?

Comment: I can add a new skill independently then when I can assign many employees to this skill via employee_skills

Comment: Exactly that is why you need a has_many through relationship. Try out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your situation is a good candidate for has_many_through association

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :employee_skills
 has_many :skills, through: :employee_skills
end

class EmployeeSkills < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :employee
 belongs_to :skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :employee_skills
 has_many :employees, through: :employee_skills
end
```

Now simply do

```
Skill.first.employees
```

Comment: I'm getting a "No association found for name `skill'. Has it been defined yet?" error, any tips on this?

Comment: Why to use this one, if there's a native way for that - `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Comment: Because this is extensible, and is more compatible with what OP is asking for

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no need to specify `class_name` or `foreign_key`, because `belongs_to :employee` already refers to class `Employee` and foreign key `employee_id`.

And you could use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, which is right for your needs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
end
```

And the migration:

```
class CreateEmployeesSkills < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :employees_skills, id: false do |t|
    t.belongs_to :employee, index: true
    t.belongs_to :skill, index: true
  end
end
```